# SQL SELECT to multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a basic SQL SELECT function:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT a.*,
                            b.nom_organisation
                            FROM roster a
                            INNER JOIN organisation b
                            ON a.id_organisation = b.id_organisation 
                            WHERE a.id_roster = ? LIMIT 1");

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id_roster);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();

// get variables from result.
$stmt->bind_result($id_roster, $nom_roster, $description_roster, $created_by, $creation_date, $nom_organisation);
$stmt->fetch();
```

I get a variable I called $created_by

This variable is an integer (a user id). I need to access another table called 'membre'. to get the name and surname of the user. for now I am doing another query:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT a.first_name,
                                a.last_name
                            FROM membre a
                            WHERE a.id_membre = ? LIMIT 1");

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $created_by);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();
```

It is working but seems a lot of code for not so much. Is there a way to do that in only one query?

Comment: Why not write a class/function?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I am not familiar with classes. I will try to have a look. Any idea how should I write that?

Comment: Yes I do but it's better if you learn it yourself.

Comment: Your original query already has a `join`.  Can't you figure out the additional `join` that you need to the `membre` table?

Comment: @Daan: right, working on it. Thansk anyway

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I do not know how to make multiple join in the same query but I will also check. Thanks

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is (almost) meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT r.id_roster
    , r.nom_roster
    , r.description_roster
    , r.created_by
    , r.creation_date
    , o.nom_organisation
    , m.first_name
    , m.last_name
FROM roster r
INNER JOIN organisation o ON r.id_organisation = o.id_organisation
INNER JOIN member m ON r.created_by = m.id_membre
WHERE r.id_roster = ? LIMIT 1
```

It's also a good practice to list all selected fields explicitly instead of using *

Comment: thanks for the answer. Very useful. It is nice to have an answer which solve the problem right away!

Answer (score 0):

You could join the membre table to your original query? This would be done in a similar way to the Inner join you used in your first query. You could either use an inner join again or a left join may be appropriate. Using a second join means you would not need to do two separate queries.

For more information about SQL joins, you may find http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html useful. It contains several examples of joins, for example:

An inner join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;
```

A left join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Link-only answers are discouraged because the content of the page you're linking to can change over time. Please add more explanation to your answer, including the relevant parts of the link you've provided.

Comment: Further that particular reference is actively discouraged on SO (petty rivalry I suspect) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, hope this has improved my answer.